# Loading very large data with tree structure using hibernate and grouping them

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, tree

I have a tree sturcture  with very large dataset stored in oracle tables and while loading the data, am getting  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Below is the complete scenrio:

Tree hierarchy stored in Db table "Tree_Hierarchy"

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
/ \
D   E
```

Tree_Hierarchy table data:

```
Id Node_Name   Parent_Id
1   A           
2   B           1
3   C           1
4   D           2
5   E           2
```

Each Node (A, B, C, and so on) contains minimum of 20,000 records and may grow upto 50,000 records. These records are stored into seperate table "Tree_Data". So Tree_Data table contains all the records information from each node. Also tree hierarchy/level may grow upto 30 levels. Tree_Hierarchy and Tree_Data both are JPA entity

Tree_Data table structure:

```
Id         Node_Name   Column1, Column2, Column3,.........,Column70  
1          A            dataA11, dataA21, data13,........., data170  
2          A            dataA21, dataA22, data23,........., data270  
...  
30001      B            dataA11, dataA21, data33,........., data370  
30002      B            dataA21, dataA22, data43,........., data470  
...  
60001      C            dataA11, dataA21, data53,........., data570  
...  
90001      D            dataA11, dataA21, data63,........., data670  
...  
120001     E            dataA11, dataA21, data73,........., data770
```

**Problem Statement:**
I have to group all the nodes in tree hierarchy together with the same data in Column1, Column2 into a "Map<Key, List<Tree_Data>>" with key as ID_NodeName_Column1_Column2 and then perform some analysis on the data.
So for the above tree sturcture with 3 levels, there would be 30000 entries/groups in Map with List containing 5 elements(each from A,B,C,D,E).

**Current scenario:**
Presently i have achived this as: Firstly I am loading tree sturcture into list and then loading all the data of all nodes into memory(It means I am loading 30000*5=150000 jpa entity into memory) and then grouping these using Java 8 stream.

**Problem :**
Above mentioned single request scenario is working fine with 4Gb of heap size(only with tree level 5), but as soon as second request come java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is encountered. I do understand loading such a large object into memory is insane and even 16Gb of heap size would not work with tree level of 38.

As an alternative solution, I was trying to load grouped data from db itself. Can anyone provide me with solution for loading grouped data from db or suggest any other approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need all the data to be loaded in memory. Instead define paging logic to load e.g. 100 records. Add

```
criteria.setFirstResult()
criteria.setMaxResults()
```

Load first 100 records, process them and load next 100. Continue till all the records are processed.

Even better you can load and process multiple pages the same time and do your grouping with parallel streams.

Comment: Thanks Stanislavl for your response. But I can do it with first result and max result. As i have to do analysis on the tree hierarchy. If I load first 100 results, then i might not be able to perform analysis/calculation. For me either solution is to load complete data group them and perform analysis/calculation or get the grouped data directly from db.

Comment: Why do you need to load all of them? When you calculate the grouped data you anyway go through the data in a kind of loop e.g. count them. You count first 100, then second with the calculated value. Instead of one big loop you will have loop from the first to the last page and for each page inner loop. Of course you can organize it on streams from java 8